# laravel "props" unidentified variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have the code below and get the error message

```
@props(['tagsCsv'])

    {{$tags = explode(',', $tagsCsv)}}


<ul class="flex">
    @foreach ($tags as $tag)

        <li
            class="flex items-center justify-center bg-black text-white rounded-xl py-1 px-3 mr-2 text-xs">
            < href="/?tag={{$tag}}">{{$tag}}</a>

        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

The error message: Undefined variable $tagsCsv. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I missed type the variable "tagCsv" instead of "tagsCsv" when using it on the other file. Sorry for stupid question.